# Can someone explain why print (2 and 3) just prints "3"?

Tags: python

This is a common question I've seen, but really don't get the programming logic behind it. I'm sure it's a simple solution, but one that I have yet to understand.

Comment: Because `and` returns the first value only if it is falsey. It *short circuits* when it can't produce a true value.

Comment: Python evaluates `x and y` as `if x is false, then x, else y`.  Since `bool(2)` evaluates to `True`, python returns `3`.